# JavaScript format number to day with always 3 digits

Tags: javascript, numbers, format, digits, days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

I have to output a day number that must always have 3 digits. Instead of **3** it must write **003**, instead of **12** it must write **012**. If it is greater than **100** output it without formatting.
I wonder if there's a regex that I could use or some quick in-line script, or I must create a function that should do that and return the result. Thanks!

Comment: You might check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: only correct answer is String(<yourNumber>).padStart(3,0) but as this is closed I can't really answer this

Answer (score 38, accepted):

How about:

```
 zeroFilled = ('000' + x).substr(-3)
```

For arbitrary width:

```
 zeroFilled = (new Array(width).join('0') + x).substr(-width)
```

As per comments, this seems more accurate:

```
lpad = function(s, width, char) {
    return (s.length >= width) ? s : (new Array(width).join(char) + s).slice(-width);
}
```

Comment: The first won't work for numbers with 4 digits and more.

Comment: @VisioN: The title says *"always 3 digits"*

Comment: ...though the negative index will fail in IE8 and lower.

Comment: @amnotiam Right, but there is also another phrase which can be considered differently: *If it is greater than 100 output it without formatting*. Who knows where is the right way, it's good to play safe.

Comment: @VisioN: fair enough, post updated.

Comment: Nice but use substring rather than substr which is deprecated.

Comment: @andreszs substring does not support negative indexing ( [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#differences_between_substring_and_slice) ). Best to use `slice()` instead.

Comment: @andreszs using substring doesn't allow negative value in the parameters. when given negative values it takes the value as 0. I'm using substr as of now, its working!!

Answer (score 6):

I found an elegant solution by Samuel Mullen on [his blog](http://samuelmullen.com/2012/03/left-pad-zeroes-in-javascript/). I simply optimized the `zeroes` creation.

```
function lpad(value, padding) {
    var zeroes = new Array(padding+1).join("0");
    return (zeroes + value).slice(-padding);
}
```

Usage: `lpad(12, 3)` results in `"012"`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this...

```
("00" + day).slice(-3)
```

It'll prepend the zeros, and then `.slice()` will always give you the last 3 values of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that pads a number with zeroes to a certain width:

```
function zeroFill(number, width) {
    width -= number.toString().length;
    if(width > 0) {
        return new Array(width + (/\./.test(number) ? 2 : 1)).join('0') + number;
    }
    return number + ""; // always return a string
}
```

(from [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript))

Since the original answer did not explain how the function works I'll do it here.

`width` initially contains the total length you want, so `width - number_of_digits` is the number of padding chars necessary.
`new Array(len + 1).join(str)` repeats `str` `len` times.
The regex is used to add an additional padding zero in case of a number containing a decimal point since the point was also included in the `number_of_digits` determined using `number.toString().length`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
​while ((val+"").length < 3​) {
    val = "0" + val;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WfXVn/

Answer (score 1):

I would write the following function:

```
var pad = function(n, length) {
    var str = "" + n;
    if(str.length < length) str = new Array(length - str.length).join("0") + str;
    return str;
};
```

Comment: I think you meant `.join("0")` and I think you meant to put that _before_ the `str`.