# increment number starting 0000

Tags: javascript, php, html

is there a way to display increment value display in 5 digit 0
when display on textbox, i tried puting 00000 on my javascript, inside modal i have textbox that display increment value, when i open my modal it display 1 not
00001, hope you can help me. advance thanks.

here is my sample code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="id"  id="id" readonly style="width:45%; margin-top:30px;"  value=" <?php 
              include_once('connection.php');
               $sql="select max(id)
                from test2";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                echo $row["0"];
                 ?> ">
```

and this is my javascript

```
<script>
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 00000 :  value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('id').value = value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use this line to format your number. The code is for an reference so please modify as per your need. 
All you need is to use this statment.

    var formattedNumber = ("00000" + value++).slice(-5);

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043061/1964336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the zeros when converting the number back to a string:

```
 function incrementValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id').value, 10);
    value = value || 0;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('id').value = ("00000" +  value).substr(-5);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas W. , it works :)

Comment: @ace glad to help :)

Comment: Since ES2017, there is the nice function [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). E.g. `value.toString().padStart(5, "0");`, it looks like it should have better readability. Your way works aswell of course :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10841855/3355250

Answer (score 0):

Your `incrementValue` function should be like this:

```js
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id').value, 10);
    value = new Array(6 - (value + '').length).join('0') + (value + 1);
    document.getElementById('id').value = value;
}
incrementValue();
```

```html
<input id="id" value='23' />
```

Comment: thank you for the answer :)

Comment: you are welcome